# In gnuplot how can I set rgb colour from 3 columns?

Tags: colors, gnuplot

I have 3 'columns' in my data file that specify the red, green, and blue fractions:

```
red     green   blue
0.263   0.914   0.086
0.263   0.914   0.086
0.263   0.914   0.086
1.000   0.571   0.429
1.000   0.571   0.429
```

How can I use these to plot some other columns painted by these values?
Apparently the following method is only available in 3D plots with splot:

```
rgb(r,g,b)=<some function code>
plot './data.csv' u 1:2:(rgb($8,$9,$10)) w l rgb variable
```

I can't see how I can use these values to colour the plot.

Comment: Good question.  I was scratching my head for a few moments on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the gnuplot demo [`rgb_variable.dem`](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/rgb_variable.html).  The corresponding data file looks like this:

```
0   0   0   0x000000
255 0   0   0xff0000
255 255 0   0xffff00
255 255 255 0xffffff
0   255 255 0x00ffff
255 0   255 0xff00ff
0   255 0   0x00ff00
#<snip> 
#...
#</snip>
```

Note that the 4th column isn't used until the last example -- i.e. this is *almost* what you have.  You'll have an additional transform to take your colors from the range [0-1] to the range [0-255], but that's an easy one (just multiply by 255):

```
scale(x)=x*255
rgb(r,g,b) = int(scale(r))*65536 + int(scale(g))*256 + int(scale(b))
plot './data.csv' u 1:2:(rgb($8,$9,$10)) with lines linecolor rgb variable
#                                                   ^^^^^^^^^ don't forget this:-)
```

Comment: @adifferentben -- No problem.  Happy to help :-).  Gnuplot's so cool.